# Rails / Devise bounces between unauthorized and already-signed-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have used Devise 3.5.6 in my Rails 4.2.6 app with a single `StaffUser` class without problem for a long time. The app is accessed via `staff.example.com`.

Now I have created a second `ClientUser` class to provide access to a separate part of the app, accessed via `client.example.com`.

Both user classes have their own scoped views, and extended session controllers (in the case of `ClientUser` this is solely to override the layout used).

The problem I'm having is a logged-in `ClientUser` will often loop/redirect through the following steps several times, before a protected page loads successfully:

- Requests `/foo`, response is 401 Unauthorized
- Redirects to `/client_users/session/new`
- Redirects to `/foo` with "You are already signed in" flash message

This happens on most requests in production, but rarely in development.

It will run through this loop many times (triggering Chrome's "Too many redirects" warning in the browser) before stopping on the initially requested page. At no point does the user get a chance to log in again, so they must have been authorized in the first place.

This does not appear to be affecting `StaffUser`.

**config/routes.rb**

```
constraints subdomain: 'client' do
  devise_for :client_users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'devise/client_sessions'
  }

  resources :client_app_object
end

constraints subdomain: 'staff' do
  devise_for :staff_users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'devise/staff_sessions'
  }

  resources :staff_app_object
end
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.scoped_views = true
config.default_scope = :staff_user

config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
end
```

**lib/devise/custom_failure.rb**

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    if request.subdomain == 'staff'
      new_staff_user_session_url(subdomain: request.subdomain)
    elsif request.subdomain == 'client'
      new_client_user_session_url(subdomain: request.subdomain)
    else
      # incorrect/missing subdomain
      raise CustomFailureException
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

My working theory is that Devise is trying to retrieve a `ClientUser` from the session, but is treating it as if it were a `StaffUser`, thus causing the initial 401 Unauthorized.

Could there be a race condition here?

How does devise know which user class to instantiate?

Thanks

**Edit 1 - config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_session'
```

Comment: Cookies and subdomains are tricky, maybe the session cookie is being lost between domains? Check for that, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Leito, The only change I made to session config was to rename it and force a re-auth for all users. I'll specify the root domain to ensure the same cookie is used for both subdomains, and see what effect that has

Comment: @Leito that was it, adding `domain: :all` to the session_store config did the trick. Do you want to write that up as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and write it yourself, I don't want to credit myself just for the pointer. I'm glad it help you out found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the cause of my problem was that I had extended the default Devise controllers (and my application controllers) into a namespace that conflicted with the class name of a model. Specifically `Client::*****Controller` vs `Client`.

Changing the class namespace to an unused name resolved the conflict.

The same problem also had other side-effects which confused the issue. These included `before_action` filters in extended classes not firing, perhaps because they weren't being extended properly - though I do not yet understand why this occurred silently and only intermittently.